# How to throw Validate in a method with javax.validation and without @Validate annotation

Tags: java, spring, validation

I am developing a service in Java and with spring Framework, that uses *javax.validation* annotations in the methods, like this example:

```
public void method(
    @NotNull @Positive Integer val1, 
    @NotNull @PastOrPresent Date startDate, 
    @NotNull @PastOrPresent Date endDate);
```

When I write the annotation @Validated in the class, it work fine, however I have some problems with Circular dependencies in some classes [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754448/validated-services-cannot-autowire-themselves/58754565#58754565) and the annotation @Validated produces **UnsatisfiedDependencyException** errors. (I will not be able to change to @Lazy, but in spite of I have to validate with javax.validation annotation).

Therefor, I want to validate the method programmatic, however I have not found the way to do it for methods yet, I Only was able to from class (when I use Dto class), with the method *validate* of **Validated** class.

Does someone can tell me how to do it.

Regards.

**Updated 11/09/2019:**

I have found a way to do it from the follows method:

```
private <T> void validate(T currentObject, Method currentMethod, Object... parameterValues) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> errors=null;
    ExecutableValidator executableValidator  = validator.forExecutables();
          errors = executableValidator.validateParameters(currentObject, currentMethod, parameterValues);

    System.out.println((errors != null && !errors.isEmpty())?"There are exceptions":"There are not exceptions");
}
```

If someone can do it with reflections and easiest, I will thanks you.

---

when you use the method, you can insert in the first and second argument: **this** and **(new Object(){}).getClass().getEnclosingMethod()**, respectively.